# Get the jqGrid colModel

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How can I get the entire colModel for a jqGrid element?  I've gone through the source code a bit and also played around with some tests, but nothing seems to return the actual array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `getGridParam` - just pass the `colModel` option:

```
jQuery("#mygrid").jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'colModel');
```

You can look at the [jqGrid docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) for `getGridParam` for more information...

Comment: Interesting.  I tried that but it failed.  However, I did come up with a solution.  I also did not see 'colModel' as a possible input for getting data, only getCol.

Comment: You write absolute correct reference to the jqGrid documentation, but a wrong JavaScript statement. Correct statment should be: `jQuery("#mygrid").jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'colModel');`. It  gives jQuery("#mygrid").p['colModel'] back, so it works!

Answer (score 1):

So I did figure it out.  In the custom navigation button (onClickButton function), I just used :

```
this.p.colModel
```

Comment: While this may work, you should use the jqGrid API instead of directly accessing elements. Otherwise you could have problems down the road if the underlying implementation of jqGrid changes in a future release...