# How to hide border at header title grid in jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid, border, hidden

How to hide border at header title grid in jqgrid?
for examples : colNames:['Name','Address','School']

Comment: Do you mean the border between the column headers and the caption  (the grid title)? Why you need this? Please look at the pictures from [the page](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_it_works) of the jqGrid documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your link, very useful to me.
I mean limiting header layer on right and left border.
im just want, my frontend so simple. =)
can i hide or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correct you want to have the following column headers

[image]

instead of the standard

[image]

In the case can use `transparent` borders:

```css
<style type="text/css">
    th.ui-th-column { border-right-color: transparent !important }
</style>
```

see the corresponding demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWinoutBorderInColumnHeaders.htm). The demo still display the hovering effect in the column headers:

[image]

**UPDATED**: If you don't want to use `!important` attribute you can use the following alternative

```css
.ui-jqgrid-labels .ui-th-column { border-right-color: transparent }
```