# Change CSS of rownumber value in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid, zebra-striping

I have changed the property of the [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start) with `rownumbers:true`. Hence it is displaying the row numbers. Now I want to change the [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) of that. How can I do that?

[image]

In the above image, the CSS of the records are changed, but the CSS of the row number is not changed. Now I want to change the CSS of the row number also. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct your requirements you can include the following CSS style to remove the `background-image` and `background-color` inherited from the CSS class `ui-state-default`:

```css
.jqgrow .jqgrid-rownum { background-color: transparent; background-image: none; }
```

[The following demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/RowNumberStyle.htm) uses additionally the styles from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11792322/315935) on your previous question. The displayed results looks like on the following picture:

[image]

Comment: What if I want to display horizontal line to the last row only ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: You can set *another* style (with the border) on the last row. You can use inline styles.

Comment: Please give me an example for the same.

Comment: Pleae give me example by considering the above sample code which you have prepared.