# how to remove horizontal lines in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, css, jqgrid, grid, border

How do I achieve doing that?

html

```
<table id="myGrid"><table>


//in my js I make it into a jqgrid

//css
.ui-jqgrid tr.ui-row-ltr td { border: none;}
.ui-jqgrid tr.ui-row-ltr td { border-collapse:collapse}
```

The vertical lines are gone but the horizontal ones remain.

Please do not offer me to look at a different answer as the suggestions did not work which is why I am posting - I need the lines removed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove vertical lines in jqGrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790302/remove-vertical-lines-in-jqgrid)

Comment: There is an answer on this post that is quite thorough on how to remove all borders: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790302/remove-vertical-lines-in-jqgrid

Hope it works for you! Give it a shot!

Comment: I did, Brian and none of these worked.

Comment: And like I said, I need HORIZONTAL lines removed, I managed to remove vertical ones.

Comment: @sarsnake: Do you tried [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/RemoveBorders.htm) from my old answer (see Brain's comment)? Does it work? Probably it could be important to know **which version of jqGrid you use and which for of jqGrid** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[My old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790302/remove-vertical-lines-in-jqgrid) should provide the main idea of "removing" the vertical and horizontal borders of grid cells. The solution can depends on which jqGrid fork (([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)) and in which version you use jqGrid.

I tested just now with free jqGrid 4.9.2 and the the following CSS rules inserted *after* `ui.jqgrid.css` "removes" successfully horizontal borders

```css
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow > td,
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgroup > td,
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqfoot > td,
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqfoot > td,
.ui-jqgrid tr.ui-subgrid > td {
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

and the CSS rules

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv tr.ui-row-ltr > td {
    border-right-color: transparent;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv tr.ui-row-rtl > td {
    border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

"remove" vertical borders of cells of the grid.

Comment: @sarsnake: Just one remark. I see that you used voting only 364 times in 6 years, 9 months. Probably you don't know that you have right to vote about **30 times a day** (see more detailed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/147495)). Voting is the main criteria for sorting by searching engine. So voting helps other people to find helpful information on stackoverflow. Thus If you find some question/answer helpful please vote it. It helps other people to find the information. Even google uses special algorithm for stackoverflow and use voting too.